# create polynomial with given list of numbers

Tags: python, list, polynomials

I want to create a `polynomial` with given coefficients (the input from a user) in Python but without `numpy` or any similar library.

using only for/while loops and lists

For example:

```
 if input is (12,2,5,3) 
     which is a0,a1,a2,a3 
  respectively, expected output is 12+2x+5x^2+3x^3.
```

I tried to separate to cases.

Comment: Do you want to create a function to evaluate the polynomial or a string representation of the polynomial? Please explain and provide more details on what is given and what is expected (in terms of variables, types, functions and classes).

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem and find out a solution for this. As I introduce myself to you as a Python Coder and I wrote this program for your required conditions.
Here's the code:

## Program to write polynomial expressions

```
lst=[12,3,56,2] # Give any set of number to this list and get the polynomial expression for that
# output ---> 12+3x+56x^2+2x^3
arr=[]
def polynomialRender(arr):
    poly=""
    for n in arr:
        if arr.index(n)==(len(arr)-1):
            poly=poly+n
        else:
            poly=poly+n+" + "
    print(poly)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    raise_power=len("x"*(len(lst)-i-1))
    cons=lst[-i-1]
    if raise_power!=0:
        arr.append(f"{cons}x^{raise_power}")
    else:
        arr.append(f"{cons}")
polynomialRender(arr)
```

It was just easy game and if you are a python language learner thent you can make any sort of customization to this code and modify it.
I hope that it must have helped you.